# Why can't my Pimoroni HyperPixel display detect multiple fingers correctly?

Tags: pi-3, python, touchscreen, driver

I recently bought *PIMORONI HyperPixel Display* (**3.5 Capacitive 800x480 display, driven by internal ADC**)
The driver is written in Python using the EVDEV lib but there are some problem reading multiple inputs (not for hardware limitation but for software one)
Using the Python script available on GitHub there are still some bugs:

1. Only 2 fingers are detected
2. If, while touching the screen with finger1, you try to touch the screen with finger2 (in different X,Y coordinates) , it read wrong and send a touchend on the finger1

Can anyone help me implementing a correct and stable driver for this device?

Driver link 
https://github.com/pimoroni/hyperpixel/blob/master/requirements/usr/bin/hyperpixel-touch

Comment: Can you please add a link for the current driver?

Comment: Off course, https://github.com/pimoroni/hyperpixel/blob/master/requirements/usr/bin/hyperpixel-touch

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please edit your question to include the link instead of providing it via comments. Thanks!